# How to set a custom Size to exporting image in react-konva?

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva

I have created a responsive stage using react-konva, but I cannot find a way to set a custom size to export the image. usually, right-click and saving the image is working as the size in the window at that time has. I wanted to add a button to download the image, but I couldn't set up a way to do that because I'm new to react hooks, I couldn't find a way to set up the data URL. please kindly refer to this

```
    import React, { Component, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import { Stage, Layer, Text, Image, Rect, Transformer, Circle, Line } from "react-konva";
    import card01 from "../images/01.jpg"
    import useImage from "use-image";
    import "./styless.css";
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
    
    const WIDTH = 875;
    const HEIGHT = 500;
    const ZOOM = 1;
    
    class Canvas extends Component {
      state = {
        stageWidth: WIDTH,
        zoom: 1,
      };
    
      render() {
        
        const { containerWidth } = this.props;
        var scale = (containerWidth / WIDTH) * ZOOM;
        let width = WIDTH * scale;
        let height = HEIGHT * scale;
        console.log({ containerWidth, width, height, scale });
    
        const LionImage = () => {
            const [image] = useImage(card01);
            return <Image image={image} width={width} height={height} scale={scale}/>;
          };
    
        return (
          <div style={{ width: `100%`, border: "1px solid grey" }}>
          
            <Stage width={width} height={height} scale={scale}>
              <Layer>
              <LionImage />
              <Text
                x={containerWidth / 10}
                y={scale*35}
                text="Some text"
                fontSize={28}
                fontFamily="Poppins"
                fill="gray"
                scaleX={scale}
                scaleY={scale}
    
                width={width}
                height={height}
              />
              </Layer>
            </Stage>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        zoom: 1
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        this.checkSize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.checkSize);
      }
    
      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.checkSize);
      }
    
      checkSize = () => {
    
        const containerWidth = this.container.offsetWidth;
        const containerHeight = this.container.offsetHeight;
        this.setState({ ...this.state, containerWidth, containerHeight });
    
      };
    
      render() {
        const pWidht = this.state.containerWidth
          ? `${this.state.containerWidth * this.state.zoom}px`
          : "100%";
    
        return (
            <>
          
            <div
                style={{ width: "80%", height: "100%", left: "10%", position: "absolute" }}
                ref={(node) => {
                    this.container = node;
                } }
            >
                <div style={{ overflow: "auto;", width: `${pWidht}` }}>
                    <div>
                        <Button color="inherit" size="small" variant="outlined" sx={{boxShadow:3}} style={{marginTop:"20px",marginRight:"10px",marginBottom:"10px", fontSize:"12pt", color:"white"}}
                            type="button"
                            value="+"
                            onClick={() => this.setState({ ...this.state, zoom: this.state.zoom + 0.2 })}> + </Button>
                        <Button color="inherit" size="small" variant="outlined" sx={{boxShadow:3}} style={{marginTop:"20px",marginRight:"10px",marginBottom:"10px", fontSize:"12pt", color:"white"}}
                            type="button"
                            value="-"
                            onClick={() => this.setState({ ...this.state, zoom: this.state.zoom - 0.2 })} > - </Button>
                    </div>
                    <Canvas containerWidth={pWidht.replace("px", "")} />
                </div>
            </div>
      
            </>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const X = () => {
      return <App />;
    };
    
    render(<X />, document.getElementById("root"));
    export default App;
```

Comment: so it's working great,, and thank you very much. i have one more problem that, how to set a image size like width 336x height 192 to the downloading image?

Comment: is it possible to set a size to exporting image here???                                      
 handleExport = () => {
    const uri = this.stageRef.current.toDataURL();
    this.downloadURI(uri, "stage.png");
  };

Comment: is there a way to set an mui select to set the text font.? i have added text fields to set the stage text succesfully. but i culdnt find a way to set the stage text font family via mui select component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `ref` to the `Stage` and get the image URL and download it.

1. In your Canvas component create a `ref` using `createRef`.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.stageRef = createRef(null);
  }
```

2. Add the `stageRef` to your `Stage`.

```
<Stage  ... ref={this.stageRef}>
        ...
        ...
</Stage>
```

3. Add two following utility functions, `downloadURI` to download image as a file and `handleExport` to get the data URI from the `ref`.

```
  downloadURI = (uri, name) => {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

  handleExport = () => {
    const uri = this.stageRef.current.toDataURL();
    this.downloadURI(uri, "stage.png");
  };
```

4. Add a new button with the click handler set to `handleExport` function.

```
<button onClick={this.handleExport}>Download</button>
```

Working example:

[image: Edit practical-elgamal-evik50]

#### Manually setting the image size

Use the following utility function which will change the image `width` and `height` using the data URI received from the Stage `ref`.

```
resizeImage = (url, width, height, callback) => {
  var sourceImage = new Image();

  sourceImage.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, width, height);
    callback(canvas.toDataURL());
  };

  sourceImage.src = url;
};

// fixed the image size to 200px by 200px before download
handleExport = () => {
  const uri = this.stageRef.current.toDataURL();
  this.resizeImage(uri, 200, 200, (sizeUpdatedDataURL) => {
    this.downloadURI(sizeUpdatedDataURL, "stage.png");
  });
};
```

[image: Edit blissful-bose-5fw3kl]

Comment: so it's working great,, and thank you very much. i have one more problem that, how to set a image size like width 336x height 192 to the downloading image?

Comment: You can keep two inputs to set image width and height as you need. I have updated the code sandbox

Comment: is it possible to set a size to exporting image here??? handleExport = () => { const uri = this.stageRef.current.toDataURL(); this.downloadURI(uri, "stage.png"); };

Comment: That is also possible. Keep another util function to set width and height manually to the data URI received from ref. updated the answer !

Comment: thank you very very much..✌️✌️

Comment: thank you very very very much.....✌️✌️✌️

Comment: isthere a way to set an mui select to set the text font.? i have added text fields to set the stage text succesfully. but i culdnt find a way to set the stage text font family via mui select component.

Comment: this should be another question actually. you can do it using css. find the css identifier by inspecting the mui input and set the css with font styles.  you may need additional wrapper class.